# Stream video from Google Drive to HTML video tag WITHOUT iframe

Tags: javascript, html, http, google-drive-api

I have a movie uploaded in Google Drive. I right clicked and got it source url something which starts with rr4 or something like that. But when I add the to the 'src' attribute, the video doesn't load. **I don't want to use iframe as I already have a custom video player.**

Is there some way to stream it? I also tried by using the Google Drive API, but it said that there were many requests being sent so it didnt load the video.

I also tried the suggested solution but it doesn't work.

Here is the code :-

`<video src="https://rr1---sn-hgn7yn76.c.drive.google.com/videoplayback?expire=1648770450&ei=UgVGYobWJ8b78gSS2YyoAw&ip=188.50.148.206&cp=QVRJWkhfT1RTQVhPOl8tTVVjWGJQaHNBZ1Vsc0k3VWY4ajZfQVdYSkhJaVhKUjhvbU1TNWdrYlA&id=59f884380d9bb40c&itag=22&source=webdrive&requiressl=yes&mh=l6&mm=32&mn=sn-hgn7yn76&ms=su&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=20&ttl=transient&susc=dr&driveid=1l2jlvkPAfAvv5q6BM-ElFbY0igTW8hVK&app=explorer&mime=video/mp4&vprv=1&prv=1&dur=5942.102&lmt=1595703658533028&mt=1648755630&subapp=DRIVE_WEB_FILE_VIEWER&sparams=expire,ei,ip,cp,id,itag,source,requiressl,ttl,susc,driveid,app,mime,vprv,prv,dur,lmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgartcYHEr-2Khnpz_St-ESk2CQCXqPe59FsLq6NZDeXgCICEOjhR-HydSMsvaLEhLmYuEBEVaJk01I06DE0G4onmQ&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAN3HrOPI41Mo1_f6GoX6W6Z8JvugRCGRbA3h84eYjO0gAiEAycoXt_9u5p1MVZLB_b3OMW8jtbnNKBb_XRNAatER0yE=&cpn=tpYVSVcfO97o1tr2&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=1.20220329.01.00" controls></video>`

Comment: Please see if the duplicate linked answers your question.  If it doesn't, please edit your question and explain why this question is not a duplicate with additional details so that we can further diagnose your problem.

Comment: Look at the second answer to the same question under the section "By Using Video Tag".

Comment: @zero298 I tried it but it doesnt work